# Want to only accept certain email address in html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email

I'm creating a form where only a certain email address is accepted. If the wrong address is used, then a message should appear.
I want to use something like ".pattern != email" within my script, however I understand this attribute can only be used within input. I've tried to use .match as well without any success.

This is a snippet of the form:

```
<form onsubmit="return validation()">
<label for="email"> <b> Email: </b> </label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="emailinput" placeholder="Please enter email" 
            pattern=".+@gmail.com"> <span id="message"></span>
</form>
```

The relevant script:

```
<script>
funcion validation() {
if (document.getElementById("emailinput").pattern != ".+@gmail.com") {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML 
    = "<em> Must be a gmail '@gmail.com' account </em>";
    return false;
else
    return true;}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@(gmail.com)` will match `@gmail.com` specifically...

`@` matches the @ symbol

Something like

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+[\S]
```

for the portion before your @ section may work...

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+[\S]@(gmail.com)
```

Run your email through a function and return `regex.test(email)`, this will return a Boolean value that can be used in a conditional.

```js
let email = document.getElementById('email');
let b = document.getElementById('b');
const emailIsValid = (email) => {
  return /[\S]+@(gmail.com)/.test(email)
}

b.addEventListener('click', function() { 
  emailIsValid(email.value)?
    console.log(emailIsValid(email.value)):
    console.log(emailIsValid(email.value) + ':  ' + email.value + ' is not valid gmail address!');
  
})
```

```html
Enter an email: <input id="email"> <button id="b">Test It</button>
```

Comment: What if user add GMAIL.COM instead of gmail.com? How we can make it this way?

Comment: @Ankitsethi Simply add an ***or*** => `||` to the return `/[\S]+@(gmail.com)/.test(email) || /[\S]+@(GMAIL.COM/.test(email)`

Comment: Thanks but user can also input Gmail, gMail and something like this. I tried adding /i to ignore case. But not worked.

Comment: @Ankitsethi try the following `/[\S]+@(gmail.com)/i.test(email)`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/ignoreCase